# How do I get Parslet to tell the the char that failed?

Tags: ruby, parslet

I've got the following in Parslet.

```
'] at line 1 char 27.
|        |- Expected "\n", but got "\\" at line 1 char 27.
|        `- Expected "\r\n", but got "\\n" at line 1 char 27.
```

which I'm slightly confused about as there isn't two slashed in the original string. To help me debug, is there a way of outputting the particular char and preferably the ordinal number too? Or do I have to refer back to the original string?

Comment: please include your parser code.

Comment: "\\" refers to the '\' character I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to handle line end being "\n" or "\r\n" but your input string literally have a '\' and a literal 'n' which means the escaping in your input string isn't right.

It's probably a use of ' instead of "

eg.

```
irb(main):001:0> "\\n".length
=> 2
irb(main):002:0> "\n".length
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> '\n'.length
=> 2
```